# How to run my Spring tests before every commit/push?

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, testing

Surprisingly, I was not able to find a this question on this website, so here it comes :

How can I run my Spring tests before every git commit/push (CLI, GUI and IDE integration) and have this command fail on test fail ?

I am aware of the existence of git hooks and run my tests using `mvnw test`. How to combine this to get the described behavior ?

Comment: That's where CI/CD comes in. You need a server that will actually run the tests, otherwise there's no use in signalling "this code needs to be tested".

Comment: @Kayaman Can't I have a hook to *locally* run the whole test suite and block the commit/push on fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any (bash) script as a git pre-commit or pre-push hook. Git should abort if the script returns a non-zero return code.

So create a script named `pre-commit.tests` or `pre-push.tests` that looks roughly like this

```
#!/bin/bash
mvnw test
```

and register the hook, e.g. by placing the script in `.git/hooks`.
`mvn test` should already return a non-zero return code if tests fail.

If not you would need to determine whether the tests succeeded in your script. For instance by piping the result to grep and looking for an ERROR entry or a more indicative line that either indicates success or failure.

Note: If you happen to be working in a Windows/Mac environment you'd likely need to adapt this based on how you integrated git, i.e. whether you run in a bash-compatible console or not.